# Using substrings for character manipulation is very expensive. Alternatives are painful. Any suggestions?

Tags: bash, substring

I have an algorithm which requires character level manipulation of very large strings. It turns out the bash substring mechanism `c=${string:$curchar:1}` is extremely expensive, with a cost that seems to grow with the length of the string. Tests show it is worth doing unnatural acts to copy very large strings into arrays of characters and operate on them.   Consider the following code, which accesses a large string using each method, inside a nested loop to show the impact of slow access on an algorithm.

```
#!/bin/bash
array() 
{
    curchar=0
    while read -n 1 c ; do
            chars[$curchar]="$c"
            curchar=$((curchar+1))
    done <<< "$1"

    len=$curchar
    while [ $len -gt 0 ] ; do
            curchar=0
            while [ $curchar -lt $len ] ; do
                    c="${chars[$curchar]}"
                    printf "[%c]" "$c"
                    curchar=$((curchar + 1))
            done    
            len=$((len / 2 ))
            printf "\n"
    done    

}        
string()
{
    len="${#1}"
    while [ $len -gt 0 ] ; do
            curchar=0
            while [ $curchar -lt $len ] ; do
                    c=${1:$curchar:1}
                    printf "[%c]" "$c"
                    curchar=$((curchar + 1))
            done    
            len=$((len / 2 ))
            printf "\n"
    done    
}

usecut()
{
    len="${#1}"
    while [ $len -gt 0 ] ; do
            curchar=1
            while [ $curchar -le $len ] ; do
                    c=$(echo $1 | cut -c "$curchar")
                    printf "[%c]" "$c"
                    curchar=$((curchar + 1))
            done    
            len=$((len / 2 ))
            printf "\n"
    done    
}

$1 "$(cat $2)"      # call one of these with a passed string
```

- *array* turns a string into an array of characters, and accesses them in a nested loop using array mechanisms;
- *string* does the same but accesses them in a nested loop using substring 
  mechanisms;

A suggestion to try `cut -c` was made and tried - it is indeed substantially better than sub-strings, but still much more expensive than character arrays.

- *usecut* uses the cut command to capture the character.

Here are the results for a small (~12K characters) comparison:

```
$ time ./substring_very_expensive.sh array longline > /dev/null

real    0m0.653s
user    0m0.644s
sys     0m0.006s
$ time ./substring_very_expensive.sh string longline > /dev/null

real    0m16.427s
user    0m16.401s
sys     0m0.019s
$time ./substring_very_expensive.sh usecut longline > /dev/null

real    1m45.809s
user    1m19.733s
sys     0m25.026s
```

Needless to say, having to build character arrays, particularly considering  the string surely must be one already in the underlying system, is painful.  Is there a better way to access the string characters directly and efficiently?

Comment: You could use cut -c

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I can't see how to not involve expensive sub-shells.  The string's too long to be a parameter, so it has to be piped to the subshell: ` c=$(echo $1 | cut -c "$curchar")` That is indeed much faster than substring but still slow: `$ time ./substring_very_expensive.sh usecut longline > /dev/null

real 1m45.809s
user 1m19.733s
sys 0m25.026s`

Comment: Good stuff! But I guess the trade-off is that if you want fast processing, you have to do the painful coding. "the string must be already in the underlying system". ... Well that's what `c/system` programming is about (I think).  `cat $2` means you're reading your string from a file. The shell is going to "store" that value in the resources it has available. 1. its environment, 2. the file system 3,a tmp store, ie a pipe. Substrings on a 12K string (small as you say, what is your true required size?) seems like a 6 sigma use case. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry - my thought was just  c=$(echo $1 | cut -c "$curchar")` .  If shell operations are too slow, it's probably time to look at ramping up to another scripting language (awk or perl, etc), or to a C (or other) program.  Good luck !

Comment: I'm doing the algorithm in a number of languages.  ruby is wonderful, small, clean, screaming fast.  I'm just exploring bash and its ... ahem ... awkward pain.

Comment: @user3546411: bash was never intended to be used as a general purpose programming language, and it is not optimized for such uses. Handling big strings will be slow. If you have complicated computations on large strings, use a language optimized for that use case.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you should at least be aware of if you're doing string processing in bash is that bash is locale-aware; in a locale with multibyte string representations (such as UTF-8), bash will compute lengths and substring indices on the basis of *characters*, not bytes.

If you prefer byte counts, you can speed things up a lot by setting the locale to `C`. (In my tests, it seems to double the speed of length and substring expansions.)

However, that will still be slow for large strings; bash was simply not designed to be an efficient general purpose programming language. It does a lot of string copies, but that overhead is usually negligible compared with process forks. If you're working with multimegabyte strings, though, you'll notice the slowness, and about the only plausible advice is to use a language which is better optimized for the use case you have.